# Program exits before done - concurrency issue in for loop - goroutine not working

Tags: for-loop, go, concurrency

**My Go project breaks when I try to write concurrently.**

I have a map `map[string][]strings`. I want to write files concurrently, which are named as `key + ".csv"` and for each value of `[]strings` write another row to the file with the value in it.

**What I've done:**

```
for key, val := range varValMap {
        go writeCsv(key, val)
    }
```

**And the func is:**

```
func writeCsv(variable string, values []string) {
    fName := variable + ".csv"
    fPath := filepath.Join(xmlFolder, "_varval", fName)
    file, err := os.Create(fPath)
    check(err)
    defer file.Close()
    for _, value := range values {
        fmt.Fprintf(file, value + "\n")
    }
}
```

The program finishes with no problems detectable by me, yet with no complete result (some files are written but nothing in them), also when I remove `go` from `go writeCsv(key, val)` all is well in go land.

Comment: Please show the code around your main loop. It doesn't look like you're waiting for the goroutines to exit. I would expect to see something like a [sync.WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup)

Comment: There is no code after for loop, it is the end of the func main().

Comment: Then that is your problem. Your program exits before anything is written.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're not waiting for your goroutines to finish. This means that as soon as your for loop is done launching all the goroutines, the program exits. Any goroutine still running is aborted.

You can use a [sync.WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) as a simple way to wait for execution to be finished:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for key, val := range varValMap {
    wg.Add(1)
    go writeCsv(&wg, key, val)
}
wg.Wait()
```

And change your `writeCsv` to notify the wait group:

```
func writeCsv(wg *sync.WaitGroup, variable string, values []string) {
    defer wg.Done()
    // do everything.
}
```